# What do you do if your consulate general violates the law?

Tags: international

If you live abroad as a foreign national, there are certain government services that you must keep obtaining from your own government through a Consulate General (e.g. passport issue/renewal).

However, if the Consulate General fails to provide such services in a satisfactory fashion, and the complaints go unanswered, is there any recourse?

For example, if you're a Russian citizen living abroad, and you suspect that the Consulate General violates your rights granted through Russian law, it's not like you can just sue them to defend your rights in the American or English court, or is it?

Comment: As it stands, this question is very broad. Unless there are any international treaties that govern this topic (and I don't think there are), the answer will vary wildly depending on the foreign national's countries of citizenship and residence. You should probably narrow the question to a specific case.

Comment: @cpast, i don't think `consular-immunity` tag is correct here, because it's the "foreign" law that's being violated, not the local one, so, there's no immunity at stake

Answer (score 2):

Any recourse is through the consulate country's government.  International Law does not provide for one country to meddle in the administrative affairs of another.

The only other recourse is to seek asylum or citizenship in another country from which you might obtain whatever services are being denied to you.